# Linux Assembly segmentation fault print using loop

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I'm writing an assembly program that would print even numbers between 0-9 using a loop. I encountered this problem, segmentation fault while running the code. I check other answers on the site but couldn't find an answer that satisfies my issue.

I suspect that the function nwLine might be the source of the problem.

```
;;this program prints even numbers from 0-8 using loop function
section .text
   global _start
   cr db 10

_start:                 ;tell linker entry point
   mov ecx, 5
   mov eax, '0'

evenLoop:
   mov [evnum], eax     ;add eax to evnum
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   push ecx

   mov ecx, evnum        
   mov edx, 1        
   int 80h
   call nwLine

   mov eax, [evnum]
   sub eax, '1'
   inc eax
   add eax, '2'
   pop ecx
   loop evenLoop

nwLine:                 ;function to move pointer to next line
    mov eax,4 ; System call number(sys_write)
    mov ebx,1 ; File descriptor 1 - standard output 
    mov ecx, cr 
    mov edx, 1 
    int 80h ; Call the kernel
    ret

   mov eax,1             ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int 80h              ;call kernel

section .bss
evnum resb 1
```

if anyone knows how to solve the problem with the nwLine function, please tell me.

Comment: You only reserve 1 byte for `evnum` but use 4 bytes. That is unlikely to be the cause of the fault, though. To pinpoint that, use a debugger. PS: `sub eax, '1'; inc eax; add eax, '2'` is a particularly complicated way of writing `add eax, 2`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, that loads the address all right.

Comment: Where does `evnum` get initialized to point to a valid memory address? It looks like you're trying to dereference `[evnum]` w/o initializing it, i.e., you seem to be saying `*evnum = 5;` w/o making it first point to a valid memory location.

Comment: @ray, no that is also fine. It's not dereferenced.

Comment: The actual problem is that the `mov eax, 1; int 80h` has to be moved up to before `nwLine`, or else the code will fall through withouth a `call` into there after the last number is printed and so the `ret` will fault. Nothing a debugger would not have shown, duh.

Comment: @Jester Need to refresh my x86. I see what you mean with the `mov eax, 1; int 80h` fall-through, but I'm still not clear on why the `mov [evnum], eax` is ok; IIRC, the brackets are used to de-reference the value of `evnum`, effectively treating it like an address and trying to access that address to set a value, right? Why wouldn't that cause a segfault?

Comment: No, `[evnum]` is not dereferencing the content of `evnum`, it just gives you the content as opposed to the address. Remember that symbols are addresses, so when you write `evnum` you really write `&evnum` and that's how `[evnum]` becomes `*&evnum` :)

Comment: Looks completely ok except ending, does it segfault after last number? (in debugger, if you step)... after the `loop` runs 5 times, the `ecx` should be zero, and the code will continue into `nwLine` without `call`, so the `ret` at the end of `nwLine` will return to some "address", which is value at top of stack, that's the source of crash (probably, I didn't run it, just reading). Put after `loop` `int 80h` with service number of exit/terminate app. That said, the code can be simplified a lot, like for example doing `add byte [evnum], 2` instead of all that fetching+sub+inc+add+store, etc.

Comment: Beyond what others have said I hope this is on Linux and not OS/X

Comment: @MichaelPetch Sorry, yeah this is on Linux.